# MD5 Model loading Massive index buffer DirectX 11

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I've been trying to follow along with an MD5 model loading tutorial from:

http://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewtutorial/q16390-27-loading-an-md5-model

I've managed to get the model loading, but when I run the program I get a black screen. When I move the camera the model is there.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/bINXwcq.png]

When I check the index buffer, the last DrawIndexed call has a stupidly large amount of indices.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/36XhQmR.png]

Comment: Half a million triangles in a complex scene is not unheard of for film-quality models. You didn't mention what Direct3D Feature Level card you have, but if you have a 9.1, 9.2, or 9.3 device they don't require support more than 1048575 primitives submitted in a single call.

Comment: Lol. This is nowhere near a film quality model though, it's just a basic maybe 1100 tri model. I just don't get why it has a stupidly large number...

Comment: You have a bug in your code somewhere if the model isn't that big.

Comment: 1572864 is 0x180000, looks like a mask to me.

Comment: You can check "Pipeline Stages" in Visual Studio and then check what is going on in this particular drawcall in Input Assebler stage. Also, there is a tool called Intel GPA (Graphics Performance Analyzer), you can capture a single frame and actually see the geometry for this particular drawcall, really handy for debugging.